# importing value to request string from input

Tags: python, string

I am a sort of new programmer and I am trying to code a script with a request function in it like here `r = requests.post("https://google.com", data=)` but instead of it being a specific chosen URL from the script I need it to be a selected input, say if i want to change the `r = requests.post("https://google.com` to  **Https://www.youtube.com** instead of it being in the script it is a input function and can be chosen by the user and then store it in a .txt file then be called again as something like `r = requests.post("url.txt")`

Comment: So what do u want to do? Just store the input in a variable, then do requests.post(variable_name). Then open a file, and store the url in there. Then open the file later and read the url.

Comment: Yeah, Pretty much

Comment: So what do you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask for url as user input:

```
my_url = input('enter url')
```

save it to text file:

```
with open('url.txt', 'w') as txt_file:
    txt_file.write(my_url)
    txt_file.close()
```

Read from the text file:

```
with open('url.txt', 'r') as my_url_file:
    read_url = my_url_file.read()
    my_url_file.close()
```

so you can try something like:

```py
my_url = input('enter url')

with open('url.txt', 'w') as txt_file:
    txt_file.write(my_url)
    txt_file.close()

with open('url.txt', 'r') as my_url_file:
    read_url = my_url_file.read()
    my_url_file.close()

r = requests.post(read_url )
```